# Unicode backspace key symbol ⌫

Tags: unicode

Is there a Unicode symbol for the backspace key ⌫, the x inside a left-pointing arrow?

I know that Unicode has a "BACKSPACE" control character ([U+0008](https://codepoints.net/U+0008?lang=en)) that it inherited from ASCII, and it has a "SYMBOL FOR BACKSPACE" character "␈" (typically rendered "BS", [U+2408](https://codepoints.net/U+2408?lang=en)) to visualize said control character, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Unicode character [U+232B](https://codepoints.net/U+232B?lang=en) "ERASE TO THE LEFT", rendered as ⌫, is used to represent the backspace key on a keyboard.

Comment: Nice. You can also add "↵"  U+21B5 (Downwards Arrow with Corner Leftwards) for the enter key.

Comment: There is also ⌦ [U+2326](https://codepoints.net/U+2326) "ERASE TO THE RIGHT" for the Forward Delete key.